# <meter> element’s value is not recognized in structured data

Tags: microdata, structured-data

According to the [Microdata specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#values),

If the `<meter>` element has the `[value]` attribute and it is an itemprop, then the itemprop value should be the value of that `[value]` attribute.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
  <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0">
  <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="1">
  <meter min="0" max="1" value="0.4" itemprop="ratingValue">Poor</meter>
</div>
```

The value of **ratingValue** should be **0.4**, however, it is incorrectly displayed as **Poor**, which is the textContent of the element.

Test it in Google’s [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). The same result is obtained with Yandex’s [Structured Data Validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/).

[image: Screenshot of Google’s SDTT showing 'Poor' as the itemprop value.]

**How do I get the machine to recognize the `[value]` attribute as the correct value?**

By the way, any additional info on where I can submit bugs for these tools would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think it should be part of the question to ask about how to report bugs to the tool providers. If considered on-topic here, it could be its own question, I guess. Anyway, both tools offer a way to provide feedback (Yandex: "Feedback" link in the footer; Google: "Feedback" button hidden behind the gear icon).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this seems to be a bug in their tools.

#### Two workarounds

- Add a `content` attribute with the value (valid according to W3C’s [current Working Draft of *Microdata*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-microdata-20171009/#content-models)):

  ```html
  <meter min="0" max="1" value="0.4" content="0.4" itemprop="ratingValue">Poor</meter>
  ```
- Move the `itemprop` to a `meta` element (valid according to all Microdata specs):

  ```html
  <meter min="0" max="1" value="0.4">Poor</meter>
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="0.4">
  ```

Comment: unfortunately, both workarounds require duplicate code